# App crashing on iOS device

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor

EDIT - I downgraded back to METEOR@1.1.0.3 and everything is working again. Looks like there's something wrong in Meteor's 1.3 release

I have an app that I built in meteor. I recently upgraded Meteor to the latest 1.3 Beta.

My app works on the iOS simulator, on an iOS device when I build and run for the device through XCode, however it crashes on devices when downloading the app through Testflight. Everything worked before the upgrade.

The splash screen will show for half a second and then the app will quit.

I'm at a bit of a loss here. What could be causing this?

EDIT 2 - Found a different log. I think this is the one we need.

```
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[366] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E04C2844-B735-4BA2-B54A-9202F6EA5C6F (sandbox)
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone ReportCrash[367] <Error>: task_set_exception_ports(B07, 400, D03, 0, 0) failed with error (4: (os/kern) invalid argument)
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone ReportCrash[367] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 366
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone ReportCrash[367] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process VUSE Videos[366]
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:rocks.brownchikenbrowncow.app[0x4a08][366]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone ReportCrash[367] <Notice>: Saved report to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/VUSE Videos_2016-02-21-132303_iPhone.ips.beta
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone SpringBoard[43] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:rocks.brownchikenbrowncow.app[0x4a08]' crashed.
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone wifid[70] <Notice>: WiFi:[477771783.972406]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: networkd apsd 
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16e75b10; rocks.brownchikenbrowncow.app; pid: 366; hostpid: -1> to 2, priority: No such process
Feb 21 13:23:03 iPhone assertiond[58] <Warning>: Could not set priority of <BKNewProcess: 0x16e75b10; rocks.brownchikenbrowncow.app; pid: 366; hostpid: -1> to 4096, priority: No such process
Feb 21 13:23:04 iPhone locationd[64] <Notice>: Gesture EnabledForTopCLient: 0, EnabledInDaemonSettings: 0
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @Kyll Sorry, I thought there might be some common pitfalls that I should look for, which is why I asked.

Can't delete now because there's already been an answer :(

Comment: You can [edit] in order to provide an [mcve].

Comment: @Kyll I wouldn't know where to start. The app worked fine before upgrading to Meteor 1.3

Comment: @Kyll Steps to reproduce: take any working meteor app, upgrade to Meteor 1.3; cry as you watch your app $h%t the bed; downgrade back to an older version of meteor and watch everything work again :)

Comment: Urgh, I know this kind of issue... Indeed, coming up with an MCVE is extraordinarily hard. Do you feel like trying some more and coming up with repro steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the default build setting for "Runpath Search Paths" is blank for "Release"

[image]

both targets should be set to

`@executable_path/Frameworks`

after this change, my testflight build is no longer crashing right after startup

--

i had the same problem after meteor 1.3 upgrade.  i got this error message from the device

`Dyld Error Message:
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib`

which led me to [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib / Image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104975/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib-image-not-found)

Comment: You're a life saver, I'll try this out tomorrow!

Answer (score -1):

I think, Logs will be helpful here

Open XCode -> window -> devices

Select your device on left window:

Now you will be seeing logs coming.

Clean logs from bottom of screen, and try opening your app, and when your app gets crashed, it will fill out error logs.

If you can provide those logs here, then we will be able to help better.

Comment: This really is a long comment, not an answer, since it doesn't actually provide an answer to the issue at hand... nor can it because OP didn't provide a [mcve].