# swift 4 xcode Version 9.4.1 -dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib euror

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sigabrt, swift4.1

[image]

I am not able to install app on any device... iOS iPhones and iPad. Simulator is working fine. this is the only error I get. I tried everything given on internet.

Comment: After trying all the methods available on internet and my own trial and error tricks 100 times. Finally I was able to solve it.

Comment: Goto iTunes in Mac --> accounts-->Authorize this computer

Comment: second step.... Goto developer in settings in iPad and iPhone and reindex with identifiers and clear trust computers everything. It worked for me........ .......                                 After reinstalling Mac OSHigh seria 10.13.15 version from Mac OS seirra beta latest version, to reinstalling Xcode latest version, after updating all certificates. etc etc etc... as many methods as you can think I did.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129141/2020034). It totally works.

Answer (score 1):

Cmd + Shift + K

Cmd + Option + Shift + K

This fixed my problem.