# how to get Xcode to set LC_RPATH (so that @rpath loads will work)?

Tags: xcode, linker, dylib, rpath, otool

I want to make a command-line tool with a few bundled frameworks that it needs (SDL and related libs).  I have Xcode set to "Embed & Sign" these frameworks, and this results in them being copied to the build folder next to the executable.  The resulting executable runs correctly within Xcode.

But when I try to run the same executable on the command line, it fails with:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: /Users/jstrout/Data/CPP-dev/soda/Build/Products/Debug/./soda
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      ./soda
```

even though, relative to the current (and executable) directory, the image is indeed at SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2.  The problem appears to be that rpath is not set correctly.  All my searching says that I should find an LC_RPATH command in the output of `otool -l` on my executable, but in fact there is no LC_RPATH command in there at all (despite several LC_LOAD_DYLIB commands that reference @rpath).

So.  What must I do in Xcode to get it the linker to emit the proper LC_RPATH command?  Or, if I'm barking up the wrong tree entirely: how do I get my command-line executable to reference frameworks that are sitting right next to it?

Comment: Not familiar with Xcode, but if the frameworks are really in the same folder as the executable, then as a direct linker arg, `-rpath @executable_path/` should work. As a compiler flag, `-Wl,-rpath,@executable_path/`.

Comment: That works!  I will add it as an answer (with the Xcode details).

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be (thanks to @Siguza):

1. Navigate to project settings, selecting the Target on the left and "All" on the top.
2. Under "Linking", find "Other Linker Flags", and enter `-rpath @executable_path/`

Building now produces a proper LC_RPATH command in the executable, and it is able to find frameworks sitting next to it.

Comment: The space in the `-rpath @executable_path/` splits that expression into two expressions for me. Is that how it should work?

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone, the existing answer did not work for me, but adding `@executable_path/` to **Runpath Search Paths** of my target did.

From: [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib / Image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104975/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftcore-dylib-image-not-found)