# Error: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib in Flutter for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I'm using flutter in android studio to build my iOS applications. I have **XCode 13** is installed on mac. I have recently moved from windows to mac. All of my *mini applications are working fine* on iPhone Emulators *except two of my major applications*. Upon building them, ***My application crashes on startup and crash report gives the following error:***

```
Reason: tried: '/Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/
Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bnnvczalmzdqlyblquzaiyfkgjkk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/
Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/592E30C6-E9E2-4658-B317-FA2833682817/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/91C8C35A-210B-4B0C-896F-643FB5D82265/Runner.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file), 
'/Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/592E30C6-E9E2-4658-B317-FA2833682817/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/91C8C35A-210B-4B0C-896F-643FB5D82265/Runner.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file)
Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/592E30C6-E9E2-4658-B317-FA2833682817/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/91C8C35A-210B-4B0C-896F-643FB5D82265/Runner.app/Runner
  Reason: tried: '/Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bnnvczalmzdqlyblquzaiyfkgjkk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection/libswiftCore.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/592E30C6-E9E2-4658-B317-FA2833682817/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/91C8C35A-210B-4B0C-896F-643FB5D82265/Runner.app/Frameworks/lib
swiftCore.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/bilalsaeed/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/592E30C6-E9E2-4658-B317-FA2833682817/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/91
(lldb)
```

[I have seen this solution but unable to understand it.](https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/30#issuecomment-608495255)

**Consider me as a newbie for building iOS applications using flutter.**

Comment: Got the same error after updating flutter and firebase dependencies.
Did you find the solution ??

Comment: I stopped working on that project because of this error. Still couldn't find the solution. I don't know why people aren't helping

Comment: I also didn't find the solution.
But making deployment target to 13.0 made workaround as of now.

Answer (score 11):

After long searching and testing for me works this solution:

To ensure your build is compatible with artifacts that contain Swift, set **Build Settings > Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries** to **YES**.

If you use Swift and build for iOS 12.2.0 or earlier, add **/usr/lib/swift** to **Build Settings > Runpath Search Paths** to prevent any issues with **libswiftCore.dylib**.

[Xcode preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1bsa.jpg)

Perhaps this will help you!

Comment: The second part of this solution resolved my problem, and ended a two-day search for a fix! Thanks!

Comment: adding `/usr/lib/swift` to `Build settings` works for me. Xcode 14.3. Thanks!

Comment: @Jaroslav Kovář you may live longer. Thanks a lot.