# Incompatible library version: XXX requires version 2.0.0 or later, but Runes provides version 1.0.0

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I was trying to run my iOS app on my iPhone. Project compiled nicely. But when app starts, XCode console showed:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Runes.framework/Runes
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CC8759F5-A501-400C-93A8-DCEE3BFE4770/XXX.app/XXX
  Reason: Incompatible library version: XXX requires version 2.0.0 or later, but Runes provides version 1.0.0
```

I use Cocoapods and my Podfile looks like:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'SnapKit', '~> 0.12.0'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SwiftTask', '~> 3.3'
pod 'Argo'
pod 'Async', :git => 'https://github.com/duemunk/Async.git', :commit => '9e64046b767fe11010891f5b7fe2aed613a6ee55'
pod 'TapLabel', '0.0.3'
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 1.4'
```

What should I do? Everything works fine on simulators.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is it possible that you are using a CocoaPods version older than 0.38.2?

If so, update to 0.38.2 using `sudo gem install cocoapods` and run `pod install` on your project.
There was [a recent bugfix](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/commit/d436c3065829a9e58fd1af1649fa6eb847c43387) that deals with illegal version numbers in the build settings of the linker.

As a workaround you could manually set the version of the "Runes" pod to 2 in the pod's target under `Build Settings -> Linker -> Compatibility Version`

Comment: The bug fix seems related, but unfortunately same issue happens. I fixed it by changing `Linking -> Compatibility Version` to 1 for all pods. Also filed an issue report https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3903

Comment: I have the same issue. I have CocoaPods 0.38.2 and would like to try the `Linking -> Compatibility Version` trick. What value do I insert instead of this one `<Multiple values>` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31750603/dyld-library-not-loaded-app-requires-afnetworking-2-0-0-but-provides-version-1

Comment: fixed with version 0.39.0.rc.1